# KODI and Xbox 360 controller

Tags: controller, xbox360, gamepad, kodi

I have KODI 16.1 Jarvis, windows 10 x64 and xbox 360 wired controller with installed drivers (works on steam big picture and games). I want to use this cotroller to navigate on kodi, it should be plug'n'play, but it doesn't read any input. Which is possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work fine if your trying to use KODI v17, which has the controller code reworked. But it's not yet final, so maybe wait, before jumping to the beta ;)

Comment: I will try, it also doesn't want to connect with KORE, which makes your phone as remote... but maybe because of ports on router or something... will try that also with Krypton version...

Comment: The problem is still here... I think I found where problem is, but not solution... my xbox controller is recognized as 5 axis 10 button controller with hat switch.. I was looking for solutions but I cant find anything